# rails: methods from module included in controller not available in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, helper

Strange thing – I have Authentication module in `lib/` like this:

```
module Authentication
  protected

  def current_user
    User.find(1)
  end

end
```

and in ApplicationController I'm including this module and all helpers, but method current_user is available in controllers, but not from views :( How can I make this work?

Comment: UPD: rails version 2.3.3

Comment: Ah yes, lastly, sounds like it would be advantageous to you to create this as a plugin instead of loose file in /lib.

Comment: What's the point of `return unless m < ActionController::Base`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the method were defined directly in the controller, you'd have to make it available to views by calling `helper_method :method_name`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def current_user
    # ...
  end

  helper_method :current_user
end
```

With a module, you can do the same, but it's a bit more tricky.

```
module Authentication
  def current_user
    # ...
  end

  def self.included m
    return unless m < ActionController::Base
    m.helper_method :current_user # , :any_other_helper_methods
  end
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Authentication
end
```

Ah, yes, if your module is meant to be strictly a helper module, you can do as Lichtamberg said. But then again, you could just name it `AuthenticationHelper` and put it in the `app/helpers` folder.

Although, by my own experience with authentication code, you *will* want to have it be available to both the controller and views. Because generally you'll handle authorization in the controller. Helpers are exclusively available to the view. (I believe them to be originally intended as shorthands for complex html constructs.)

Comment: i've got undefined method `helper_method' for #<Class:0xb139e5c> on 

m.helper_method :current_user  :(((

Comment: That's weird. I tested the code above. You must be including Authentication in things other than controllers. In that case, just append a condition to that line: if m < ActionController::Base

Comment: I updated the example to handle the situation where the module is included in things that are not controllers.

Comment: Same problem as Alexey Poimtsev, maybe this example if out of date for rails 3?

Comment: `helper_method` was what I was looking for. I use `current_business` a lot in my controllers and views so it makes sense just to put in the controller and make it available in views.

Comment: How do you test a `helper_method`?

Comment: ```return unless m < ActionController::Base```
```m.helper_method :my_helper_method```
But all module methods are imported as helpers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare it with

```
  helper :foo             # => requires 'foo_helper' and includes FooHelper
  helper 'resources/foo'  # => requires 'resources/foo_helper' and includes Resources::FooHelper
```

in your ApplicationController?

http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.3.1/classes/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#M001904

Comment: i already have in app controller
helper :all
is it not enought?

Comment: helper :all will only load helpers in the app/helpers dir (and in engine plugins), and I think, only if they're named something_helper.rb / SomethingHelper.

Comment: Well, then you have to do things a bit more manually. See my answer above.